# Three.js skeleton moves but geometry stays static

Tags: three.js

I've recently started fiddling with three.js and I'm trying to understand how building a skinnedMesh works. I was getting a bit lost due to the apparent lack of documentation so I just copied the code from [this](https://threejs.org/docs/scenes/bones-browser.html) example into my project to play with it a little bit and try to understand things better.

However, tho in my project the skeleton moves as expected, the geometry just stays static. The code is unchanged from the example but I can't reproduce the outcome.

Any tips would be welcome.

Below is a picture of the described behaviour.

[image: Picture of described behaviour]